# use of annotatedTimeLine plugin in jqPlot

Tags: charts, jqplot, annotatedtimeline

I am a newbie to `jqPlot` and I am currently using it to generate charts
based on some statistics. I would like to use the annotated timeline
for one of my charts. I found the plugin at https://bitbucket.org/j5bot/jqplot
. Is there any sample code to demonstrate this usage? I tried using it
in the series defaults options as:

`seriesDefaults:
{renderer:annotatedTimelineRenderer}`

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please give an example
of it's usage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, j5bot created a fork of the main jqPlot code, especially for timelines. J5 talks about it in a Google Group and provides a screencast of what it can do [here](http://screencast.com/t/mHY5eUV99XaT). There seems to be an [additional example file provided in j5bot's fork](https://bitbucket.org/j5bot/jqplot/compare/default..cleonello/jqplot%3adefault#diff) (examples/rangeSelector.php), and although I don't see it explicitly calling the annotatedTimelineRenderer, I can't really imagine what else the example file would be for, so this is probably the place to start.

J5bot also made changes to other files, so you'll need to get those versions too - not just drop the plugin into Chris' jqPlot code.